# Xcode: Breakpoints disabling themselves

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

I set a breakpoint but when I run my program it looks like it disables itself. Any ideas what's going on? The breakpoint arrow is dark blue before I run the program, and upon execution changes to light blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breakpoints in Xcode can be fickle...most of the gotchas are detailed in this SO thread:

[Why Aren't My Breakpoints Working in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790/why-arent-my-breakpoints-working-in-xcode)

Comment: Thanks. I had to turn off the lazy loading, clean my target, and restart Xcode.