# Xcode debug with iPhone app is slow and laggy

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, gdb

I am debugging an iPhone app I'm writing in Xcode, but sometimes now the debugger (which is GDB) slows a lot (doing a step-by-step debugging) and becomes unresponsive sometimes (the icons for stepping-in, stepping-over, stepping-out are not clickable), after sometimes it gets back to normal and continues and other times it stay like that forever or a message appears in console: "Timed out" (or something similar) and I can see my CPU from activity monitor going up to 90%. As a workaround I used to put a brekpoint after the line of code I was interested in and simply went with 'Continue' to 'Continue' (doing so it run perfectly fine and fast).
Can this be code dependent? Is there a way I can debug the debugger (behaviour) ?

**UPDATE**:
The complete message is

```
Timed out fetching data. Variable display may be inaccurate.
```

Googling for it i discovered that it happens when Xcode gdb is trying to look inside data formatters. Someone suggested to disable Run>Variable View>Use Data Formatter (in xcode 3.2, previous i guess it is Debug->Variables
View->Enable Data Formatters) and it seems to work for me too (till now)
So now I am asking: why? : D

**UPDATE2**:
This solved the debugger from stopping on a specific part of the code but it stil hangs (with the same message) in another calling. It seems to me that this involves some CoreData API like `(NSEntityDescription*)entityForName: inManagedObjectContext:`

**UPDATE3**:
Would it be best to cache the NSEntityDescription instead of creating always a new one?

Comment: Does it happen to all places in your code? Can you check if those codes consume computing heavily? I never suffer that before. How about your hardware details, your current Mac OS and your current XCode?

Comment: I run Xcode 3.2.2 with iPhone SDK 4 on a 2009 iMac with Mac OS X SL 10.6.4. Now i will run some test on other piece of code, but on that specific piece it behaves that way not always.

Comment: Here is the specific message: " Timed out fetching data. Variable display may be inaccurate."

Answer (score 9):

I have observed very slow debugging when 'Queue Debugging' is enabled in the scheme.  If you don't need queue debugging, consider disabling it.

Comment: This solved issue with Xcode 10.1 laggy debugging experience

Comment: This is the correct answer! Tested with XCode 10.2.1 while debugging via WiFi.

Comment: Solved. Voted for getting rid of much of time.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found some related answer on apple's discussion:

> One common cause of problems is trying to run the data formatters on uninitialized objects. We don't actually have any way to tell for sure when an object is good or not. We have some heuristics, but stack objects sometimes point to the leftovers of another stack object that are "almost good enough" and fool us. One trick that will help out with this is when you are breaking in a function, break after the objects are initialized, not at the very beginning of the function.

Comment: Sounds interesting, could you link your source?

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem and I solved it **disabling** the option "**Run**" - "**Enable/Disable Guard Alloc**" in *xCode*. Now it works so fast! Check if you have this option enabled and disable it.

Hope it helps! :D

Comment: Thanks, but **Guard Malloc** has always been disabled in my project. Plus, the kind of slowness it produces is 'correct' and different from the one I was experiencing (my debugger totally hung up)

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code in Instruments.  This could be a memory issue, so watch your utilization in Instruments as the code runs.  When you get to the part where it becomes less and less responsive, you should see the memory usage go up and be able to trace back from there in Instruments.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems normal inside Instruments. I have noticed, as said in the post, that this happens with Core Data API.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same problem as soon as i migrated to xCode 3.2. i have been using xcode 3.0 and 2.0 , i never faced this problem in those SDKs. So i think this is an issue with the new SDK.

Answer (score -1):

I'm very new to Xcode debugging, but while doing my research I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983657/iphone-device-debugging) which may be helpful to your issue.

Basically there are two people in there who had many issues with xcode debugging and the OP solved his issue through a clean install. Quoting **LucasTizma**'s 4th edit:

> FINALLY got device debugging to work.
>   I have a feeling that something
>   low-level on my device was causing
>   issues...nothing I did worked on my
>   system. However, I installed Xcode on
>   another system and device debugging on
>   the same device (with the same cable)
>   worked flawlessly. Directly after
>   that, device debugging began working
>   on my original machine, leading me to
>   believe that some strange hardware
>   flag was screwed up and somehow
>   "reset" on the second machine. In any
>   case, it works now.

Comment: that's not about device-debugging but simulator-debugging. Plus it has some more-or-less strict conditions under which it happened as stated on the question

Comment: @rano I agree... Neverthless it hints to me either Xcode have some weird bugs or is just not as simple to use as it is advertised, which leads people to think it's buggy and "reseting" it fixes it. I guess my point here was for you to try it and at least configure all the same on a different and clean machine and see if your problem persists.

Comment: @Cawas I already tried to clean and install even if not on a new machine since I only have this one : D

Comment: @rano so you actually still have the same issue since july?! :o

Comment: Only sporadically and when I debug that Core Data piece of code (and I'm not going into that since two months) btw I'm looking forward Xcode 4

Comment: @rano, well, from the answers (and lack of more consistency among them) I'd say you got yourself a pretty unique bug and, as such, you're on your own... which also means a clean install on a **different** machine still have a shot.  if it's so reproducible, get to the basics: try and isolate it (reduce the lines of code to a bare minimum) then share it with other people so we can see if it's machine-wise or not.