# Is there any way to solve XCode freeze-ups while debugging, and it can not populate the variable watch window?

Tags: xcode, remote-debugging

I often get freeze ups where XCode 4.6.1 shows me this nearly endless progress spinner and freezes for up 3 minutes before returning:

[image]

This only happens with real iPhone targets so I suspect the problem is in communication to the remote-debugger-kernel that is on the real iOS device target.

Has anyone seen this and knows of a workaround or fix?  (Other than the obvious, turn off the debugger watch window.)

Comment: Might be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760206/po-command-in-xcode-4-6-is-very-slow-the-first-time

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226311/xcode-debug-with-iphone-app-is-slow-and-laggy

Comment: How could "auto" mode be running data formatters?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. "Auto" is just a way of filtering which variables the debugger will attempt to portray in the list.

Comment: Also did you try updating to 4.6.2 (released yesterday)? They claim it makes LLDB faster. (You *are* using LLDB, I presume?)

Comment: Yes, I am. Good idea. Didn't check for updates TODAY yet. :-)

Comment: I have this issue on xCode 6.3

Comment: Try cleaning up your intermediate build products folder. (Derived Data is Apple's crazy name for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in XCode 4.6.2.
(April 15th)

If this doesn't fix your problem, or you encounter it in XCode 6, try cleaning up your binary build products (Derived Data) folders.

Comment: No, it's because I sacrificed a goat for you.

Comment: Hope you make some excellent Goat curry.  Love your iOS book by the way. Learned so much from it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into this problem occasionally with Xcode 6.4 (6E35b). I haven't tried clearing my 'Derived Data' folders, but I've discovered that switching the variables view between 'Local' and 'Auto' will sometimes cause that view to become unstuck and start working. Your mileage may vary.