# Breakpoints don't hit on iOS 5.0.1 when debugging from XCode 3.2.5

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

My program runs great on the simulator, and also runs (until a point) on my iPod touch 4th gen that's running iOS 5.0.1. When I tried to add breakpoints to debug, they didn't hit. I searched on stackoverflow and found a number of q&a's, including this one:

[Why aren't my breakpoints working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790/why-arent-my-breakpoints-working-in-xcode)

I tried those solutions, but they didn't help. One poster suggested however that you can't debug iOS 5.0.1 on XCode 3.2.5 (which I'm using, because 4.x is horribly buggy -- it won't even open my project).

So i tried debugging on my iPod touch 1st gen running iOS 3.1.3. Sure enough, breakpoints DO hit here! Problem is, it has other problems on this device I haven't been able to resolve yet (which I'll ask about separately).

So the question is: can I get debugging to work on iOS 5.0.1 using XCode 3.2.5? If not, and I need to purchase a new iPod touch just for debugging purposes, what iOS *will* work for debugging from XCode 3.2.5? How can I know before I purchase a new iPod? (Assuming there is no way to downgrade the iOS on my iPod touch that's running 5.0.1. I've read you can't downgrade.)

NOTE: When running on the iOS 5.0.1 iPod, I get this in the console *before* the program starts running:

Loading program into debugger…
unable to read unknown load command 0x25  // this is repeated about 35 times

Comment: Bump. Have same problem. Upgraded to iOS5, installed new XCode 3.2.5 and breakpoints not working when running on Device.

Comment: Same here. Tried both gdb and lldb but no difference.