# Where can I find "Load Symbols Lazily" option in Xcode6?

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, symbols

Where can I find "Load Symbols Lazily" option in Xcode6?

I Couldn't find it in 'preference'

Comment: What does the option do?  Sounds like a debugging option?

Comment: This feature is no longer available in Xcode. I'm currently using Xcode 10.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That option was specific to gdb, and went away when Xcode stopped supporting gdb.  lldb does most of the tricks that the "Load Symbols Lazily" and others, so that turning on options like this by hand should not be necessary.  If you are still seeing slow symbol loading with lldb, please sample Xcode while it is slow and file bugs with the samples.

Answer (score 8):

Load Symbols Lazily" option is not available in Xcode 6.
You can use the breakpoints from below:

Debug -> Debug Workflow -> deselect the "Always show disassembly"

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPcvm.png]