# Xcode 6 ignoring breakpoints - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

Xcode 6 is completely ignoring my breakpoints. I saw a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790/why-arent-my-breakpoints-working) from 2008, but the answers are outdated, and don't seem to work.

**EDIT:**

This is happening only with projects that I start. All my downloaded open source projects work perfectly fine, as well as projects I started a few months ago.

**UPDATE:**

This is what I get when I create a brand new project and set a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad`

[image]

Comment: Did you close and reopen the xcode. This may fix the issue.

Comment: There's *a lot* of things to try in the page you link. The last comments of the [top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/67957/2227743) are from december and january. Does not look outdated to me. Did you try everything that's over there?

Comment: @ArunGupta Tried that. It didn't work

Comment: @ericd Yes, I spent 20 mins looking at every answer. Most of them didn't even apply to Xcode 6, and the ones that did, did not work

Comment: Oh, ok. Good thing to know. Thanks.

Comment: can you post code where a breakpoint is placed that xcode ignores?
Also are you using the standard build settings?

Comment: If you click on a breakpoint after you create it, the color goes muted and the app will skip over it when you run it. Have you ruled that out?

Comment: @RMenke Using standard settings. Its happening in the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: would it still be possible to post the code? If not at a println() at the point of the breakpoint. Does that work? If not the code is just not executed and the breakpoint obviously doesn't work either...

Comment: Yes, I experienced the very same thing. After trying many, many things, I ultimately had to *completely* nuke Xcode (including removing everything in library, etc.) and reinstall from scratch.

Comment: Might be unrelated, but I am also having issues with xcode. It almost looks like it cashes files. Sometimes a build doesn't check all files for changes and uses old data. Deleting all relevant files in the library and then performing a clean helps. Xcode has been extremely buggy since swift 1.2 came out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying many different things, I ran

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

This reset my Xcode settings. Now when I create a new project, breakpoints work fine.

I realized that the problem happened when I added Cocoapods to the project. B/c right after I ran `pod install`, breakpoints stopped working. I'm not sure why.

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when I added a target to my project. Breakpoints placed in that target were ignored.

The solution was to set "Debug Information Format" in the new target's build settings to "DWARF with dysm"

In XCode 7.1 it defaulted to DWARF

Answer (score 1):

There can be various culprits for this, a common one being setting the build scheme to Release instead of Debug.

For me it was the Debug Optimization Level set to -O0 in my target's build settings. Changing it to "Fast [-O, O1]" makes Xcode breakpoint-respectful again.

[image]

There is an interesting post about it here:

http://blog.credland.net/2014/03/xcode-debugger-why-do-you-stop-working.html

Answer (score 0):

Close Xcode and remove the derived data and then reopen Xcode it will work