# XCode breakpoints is not working for a specific project

Tags: ios, xcode, breakpoints

I am using XCode 6.4, recently we created a workspace and pod files for the project and I think during this process either a file related to breakpoints or related to preferences has been deleted.

I cant figure out what happened.

Now xcode doesnt stop at breakpoints. I have almost tried anything on stackoverflow but no luck:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what about resetting Xcode settings `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`

Comment: your suggestion didnt work as well

Comment: strange because [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29924993/1836115) solved the same issue after using pods with that command

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, XCode breakpoints is not working only for a specific project and I solved in a very strange way. 
I changed the name of the project's folder. Infact, I had previously renamed the project's folder with a name that contained numbers. I have deleted the numbers and the breakpoints work again! 
I hope that someone can explain this solution because is a XCode mistery.