# Breakpoints not working with cocoa pods in Xcode7.2

Tags: ios

Lam using Xcode 7.2 and I have installed cocoa pods in my application.I am trying to set a breakpoint to debug but the same never gets triggered. I have tried creating a simple application and break point works perfectly fine.

Any inputs will be highly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check once your `build setting` mode if it is in `release mode` then change it to `debug mode`.

if it above choice is not work try this

- Make sure that the `target` -> `scheme` -> `Run` - is in Debug mode (was Release)

  - Make sure to check the option `Debug executable` like this:

  [image]

for more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790/why-arent-my-breakpoints-working)

Comment: I have checked this, everything is proper. This issue happens only after installing pods. If I don't have pods everything works fine.

Comment: @IswariyaMadhavan -- see this link it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902339/xcode-6-ignoring-breakpoints-swift

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.The problem was with "Strip Style" option under build settings. I changed  this flag to "YES"and things started working.

Comment: @IswariyaMadhavan -- it is symboilcate the all symbols , but it always set as "All symbols" , are you manually changed in before

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik I didn't do any changes manually, and I am wondering how that changed. Anyways after resetting values things stated working.

Comment: @IswariyaMadhavan -- congrats , if my answer is useful give the tick mark for the answer it is useful for future