# Xcode 7 Beta 4 - Breakpoints don't work

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcode7-beta4

In Xcode 7 Beta 4, none of my breakpoints get hit. I have checked everything recommended on this site I could find. They worked in Beta 3. Has anyone else experienced this, and if so, found a fix?

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790/why-arent-my-breakpoints-working) may be helped you

Comment: I have tried everything on that page, and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I had this problem when tackling Xcode 7 beta 5. After a while (closing app, rebooting computer, turning breakpoints on and off), they just started to work.

Not sure what the trigger was...