# Breakpoints and Logging Not Working At All

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, debugging

I have some set-up code in `viewDidLoad` that is successfully being called. The only problem is that whenever I place a `NSLog(@"random")` or a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad`, nothing is logged and execution never halts. Here's what I have tried so far to fix it:

1. Restart Xcode
2. Restart my computer
3. Delete the app from my iPhone and rebuild
4. Clean
5. Verify my build configuration is "Debug"
6. Done everything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790/why-arent-my-breakpoints-working)
7. Tried placing a breakpoint in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` and that isn't called either.
8. Verified that there is no `#define NSLog()`

If this is relevant at all, this file is Objective-C++. However, breakpoints and logging were working earlier, so I doubt that's the issue.

Comment: So breakpoints aren't working at all? It's not just a problem with this one `viewDidLoad` method? If so, you should update your title - it's misleading.

Comment: @rmaddy - You're right. It's a project-wide problem. I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the debug and release flag in project settings.

Comment: What? Of course breakpoints work on real devices. Or did you mean under specific circumstances?

Comment: No I didn't mean that...If you sure then I'm editing my answer until I check again.

Comment: I did check. The build active architecture is set to debug.

Comment: I'm sure since I've been debugging iOS apps on real devices for the last 7 years (including today). Breakpoints work on real devices.

Comment: I've been testing this project on a real device for the entirety of its duration and the breakpoints have always worked up until today, so I doubt it has anything to do with real device vs. simulator.

Comment: try creating another project and check there if something is bad with your project settings.

Comment: I tried once again but the breakpoints don't work for me in real devices. You can try cleaning your Xcode or reset your Xcode.

Comment: May be I need to find out that how it works then..Will do surely.

Answer (score 0):

On a whim I downloaded the Xcode 7.6 beta, and the breakpoints seem to work again now both in the beta and in the older Xcode I was using.