# Breakpoints not being hit in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, xcode6.4

I have an Xcode project which includes a sub project.  After upgrading to Xcode 7 breakpoints in the sub project are not hit nor can I step into functions calls of the sub project.  Some breakpoints do get hit but they just show assembly for the call so it seems the sub-project is not being symbolicated correctly.  I've checked all the usual sort of things i.e. is generating debug symbols, build configuration on debug is not release and things of this nature shown in Xcode project settings.  Anything else I might be missing?  In Xcode 6.4 this was not an issue.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue here on 7.1. I have to restart XCode to make it work.

Comment: I also see this same problem and a restart is the only way to get it working again

Comment: Restart hasn't worked for me.  Though I did get things to work switching symbol generation to just DWARF instead of DWARF with dSYM but then I don't get dSYM files generated.  My feel is this is something with project file settings.

Comment: That's weird, we had the same problem after we switched from DWARF + dSYM to DWARF only, and fixed it by reversing it.

Comment: [try this `answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790/why-arent-my-breakpoints-working/33099960#33099960). I had Deployment `PostProcessing` as `YES` in my `subproject` and setting it as `NO`worked.

Comment: Thanks @MaheswaranRavisankar.  I ended up actually resolving this by creating a test application in Xcode 7 and comparing all the debug settings to those in my breakpoint failing application.  I believe it was a mismatch on the debug information format between the parent project and sub project and matching the build configuration types between the parent and sub projects.  It's been a few years so I can't remember for sure I'm going to check my commit logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with not having the correct debug information format set in the hosting project.  I resolved by creating a dummy/test Xcode project and comparing the debug file format detailed for each configuration to that in the trouble making project changing the debug information format to match the dummy/test project.

Answer (score 0):

In some case this issue can be related with broken link between the breakpoint and the Project/file.
So try to remove the breakpoint and re adding it.