# Breakpoints are not working in Xcode 12.2

Tags: swift, xcode

I have breakpoints set throughout my program, but Xcode appears to ignore them completely.

I wanted to create a new question, because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790/why-arent-my-breakpoints-working) one was asked in 2008 and has nothing up-to-date.

Comment: The issue is something on your end. Breakpoints work for me. I think your best bet is to (a) delete all breakpoints, then (b) set a breakpoint in - for a UIKit project - in something like viewDidLoad. If you *still* aren't hitting it properly, set up more details so maybe someone here can duplicate things. As of now, it's impossible to do that with the lack of details in your question.

Comment: Tried all of the above. I just don't know how to duplicate anything because there are so many parameters and everything to go over. It also wouldn't be the best to upload the entire project.

Comment: Never said you should upload the entire project. Just take baby steps. Since breakpoints in 12.2 work for me like they always have, start there. new project, totally blank. Set a breakpoint. If it works, then it's **not** Xcode 12.2 as your question claims. And yes - now the hard part starts. Because it's obviously *something* in your Xcode project. Could be anything.... a third party plugin, a corrupt project, even a corrupt Xcode download (or worse, the hardware you are using. Start simple and acknowledge that the issue isn't Xcode (trust me on that - I actually did create a blank project.)

Comment: @dfd Yeah I know :) I seemed to have fixed the stuff in the main project, I don't actually know how though. Only problem now is it only works in the main project and no extensions, for example the widget extension or the intent one. Is there a way to fix them?

Comment: Turns out you have to attach the debugger to your extension using Debug > Attach to process PID or name > type the name of your extension. In my case "WidgetIntent"

Comment: @Lemon please add your solution as an Answer.

Comment: @pkamb I don’t think that’s a good idea because the comment there has nothing to do with the question I asked.

Comment: Wasn't the problem caused by an Extension not hitting its breakpoints?

Comment: @pkamb Read the rest of the comment thread.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you've accidentally turned off the master breakpoint switch.

[image]

It should be bright blue, not gray. Click it to toggle.

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't be the solution as it's been enabled the whole time :(.. Also also note, I have my system colour thingy set to 'green' - so it's actually bright green for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me for a very odd reason. I added rich notifications to my app. As I ran the app I was running it on one of their targets instead of the main app itself. The orange arrow points to the main target. In a situation like this make sure you aren't on the wrong target (the ones above and below the orange arrow.

[image]